# Can somebody show me how to do these step by step?${ e }^{ ln4 }\cdot e^{ 2 }\cdot { e }^{ ln2 }$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know the Answer To the question in the title is "$8{ e }^{ 2 }$"
But im confused on how to do it.

2. Also How do i Solve the following equation for y = f(x).
   $${ e }^{ y }={ e }^{ 2y }\cdot { e }^{ ln(2x) }$$
3. and how do i simplify $\ln { \left( a\cdot 4\cdot \frac { e }{ b }  \right)  } $

I appreciate any help.

Comment: $e^{\ln(x)}=x$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

Remember that the natural logarithm and the natural exponential function are each others inverse.

$$e^{\ln(x)}=x$$

so $$e^{\ln(4)} e^{\ln(2)}=4 \cdot 2$$

2.

One of the properties of the logarithm is that $\ln(a b) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)$

So if you take the logarithm on both sides of your equation you get

$$
\ln(e^y) = \ln(e^{2y} \cdot e^{\ln(2x)}) \iff y = 2y+\ln(2x) \iff y=-\ln(2x)
$$

3.

Try working it out yourself with the previous rule of multiplication and with the fact that

$$
\ln(\frac{a}{b}) = \ln(a)-\ln(b)
$$